# Indexing custom post type

Tags: algolia

I have the plugin installed in WordPress, but no matter what settings I set I cannot get custom post type to be indexed.  Is that possible through the plugin or do I need to do something else

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Grant

Comment: Grant, are you using that plugin https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-wordpress? Its not released yet, but you should be able to get something up and running using the version on the 'develop' branch.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am using.I can't remember which branch I used, try again from the dev branch (just to be sure)

Answer (score 0):

A new version of the Algolia Search plugin for WordPress has just been released.

It supports indexing custom post types an taxonomies but also users.

You can check it out here: https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/

Let me know if that solves your issue!